# WINE Installation

Tags: release-freya, wine, playonlinux

I already have WINE installed, I have installed by write this on terminal `sudo apt-get install wine`. I didn't add any PPA, and WINE worked fine.
But somehow he just disappear from my system. I notice that because I use PlayOnLinux to install some Windows apps, and yesterday when I'm trying to launch one, I've got a message saying that the WINE stoped.

And now when I try to install WINE again I've got some dependencies problems...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please copy & paste error message instead of screenshot. Also please change language to English, and [edit] the post :)

Comment: Also add output of `apt-cache policy wine wine1.6 wine1.7`

Comment: btw your problem is someway similar(dup) of https://askubuntu.com/a/700497/439451, see if useful :)

Comment: And also [here](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3287/cannot-install-playonlinux-nor-wine/3292?noredirect=1#comment5771_3292).

Comment: Any update diogo, or is it already solved?

Comment: It's solved! I just delete .wine folder from my personal folder. And run the code to install WINE.

Comment: @DiagoOliveira would you write an answer, then you can accept it after 48h.

Answer (score 2):

For a dumb reason you need to run `sudo apt-get install wine elementary-desktop` or else it might break Freya. Just be careful and use this command instead-it's what I used.

Where I got this from: click [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/2vif13/psa_do_not_install_wine_it_breaks_freya/)

Hopefully this helps :)

Alexei

Comment: Why would Freya break?

Comment: idk it deletes needed files for the system

Answer (score 2):

I installed WINE on my system using the `ubuntu-wine` PPA (personal package archive) because the software center WINE would not install and had no problems with it on my system which is freya 0.3.2 64-bit.

#### To add the PPA and install WINE run the following

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.8
```

You should now have a perfectly working WINE installation. If you have any problems add a comment to this answer